# How to display associated categories with get_adjacent_post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a Next Post link at the bottom of my Wordpress article.

I am using get_adjacent_post to display the post title. I would also like to show the attached categories with my this post.

I can't find how I should write this.
My attempt is:

```
<?php
                $prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
                if(!empty($prev_post)) {
                echo '<div class="next"><a href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_post->post_title . '"><span class="link">Next article  &rarr;</span><br/>' . $prev_post->post_title . '<br/><span class="grey">Filed under: ' . $prev_post->post_category . '</span></a></div>'; }?>
```

$prev_post->post_category doesn't work. Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_the_category_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list) should do the trick:

```
get_the_category_list( ', ', '', $prev_post->ID )
```